# Tried making a damage calculator using getElementByID but I don't think it's working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, math, getelementbyid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Riven Calculator </title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("BOOP.jpg");
}
</style>

<body style="background-color: #a6a6a6;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 align="center"> Riven Damage Calculator </h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
var level = document.getElementById('RIVEN_LEVEL');
var rivenQrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_Q');
var rivenWrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_W');
var rivenErank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_E');
var rivenRrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_R');
var bonusAD = document.getElementById('RIVEN_AD');

var rivenHP = 558.48 + (86 * level);
var rivenAD = 56.04 + (3 * level) + bonusAD;
var rivenARM = 24.376 + (3.2 * level) ;
var rivenMR = 32.1 + (1.25 * level);

var rivenQDMG = 10 + (20 * rivenQrank) + (rivenAD * (.4 + .05 * rivenQrank));
var rivenWDMG = 50 + (30 * rivenWrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
var rivenEDMG = 90 + (30 * rivenErank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
var rivenRDMG = 100 + (50 * rivenRrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04) * .6;

function myBoop() {
    console.log(rivenQDMG);
    console.log(rivenWDMG);
    console.log(rivenEDMG);
    console.log(rivenRDMG);
}

</script>

<center>
<p align="center"> Input your level: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_LEVEL"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your Q rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_Q"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your W rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_W"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your E rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_E"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your R rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_R"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your bonus AD: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_AD"> <br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myBoop()"> Calculate </button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

The point of it is to calculate the damage each ability does at a given time in the game, but every time I try to calculate with it, it says that Q does 32.416 damage, that W does 50 damage, that E shields 90 damage, and R does 100 damage. I feel like it has something to do with the getElementById parts of the code, but I'm not entirely sure.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You get the element with `getElementById()` and need to get its value property
2. You need to get the values when the function executes so move the code in the `myBoop()` function

```js
function myBoop() {
    var level = document.getElementById('RIVEN_LEVEL').value;
    var rivenQrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_Q').value;
    var rivenWrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_W').value;
    var rivenErank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_E').value;
    var rivenRrank = document.getElementById('RIVEN_R'.value);
    var bonusAD = document.getElementById('RIVEN_AD').value;
    
    var rivenHP = 558.48 + (86 * level);
    var rivenAD = 56.04 + (3 * level) + bonusAD;
    var rivenARM = 24.376 + (3.2 * level) ;
    var rivenMR = 32.1 + (1.25 * level);

    var rivenQDMG = 10 + (20 * rivenQrank) + (rivenAD * (.4 + .05 * rivenQrank));
    var rivenWDMG = 50 + (30 * rivenWrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
    var rivenEDMG = 90 + (30 * rivenErank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
    var rivenRDMG = 100 + (50 * rivenRrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04) * .6;

    console.log(rivenQDMG);
    console.log(rivenWDMG);
    console.log(rivenEDMG);
    console.log(rivenRDMG);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Riven Calculator </title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("BOOP.jpg");
}
</style>

<body style="background-color: #a6a6a6;">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<h1 align="center"> Riven Damage Calculator </h1>

<center>
<p align="center"> Input your level: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_LEVEL"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your Q rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_Q"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your W rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_W"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your E rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_E"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your R rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_R"> <br>
<p align="center"> Input your bonus AD: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_AD"> <br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="myBoop()"> Calculate </button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

**P.S.** Riven OP

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't read the JS code through thoroughly so I don't know how the calculation is built in the first place (especially because I don't know which game you are refferring to).

But when you use `getElementById()`, and you want the value the user entered in the text field for example, you have to append `.value()` at the end of it (f.e. `document.getElementById("RIVEN_AD").value();`), because otherwise you will just get back the object and not it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Declare all the variable inside the function.And you need to add `.value` of the each element value call.And Add `parseFloat` to parse the string to number

```js
function myBoop() {
var level = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_LEVEL').value);
var rivenQrank = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_Q').value);
var rivenWrank = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_W').value);
var rivenErank = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_E').value);
var rivenRrank = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_R').value);
var bonusAD = parseFloat(document.getElementById('RIVEN_AD').value);

if(!level && !rivenQrank && !rivenWrank && !rivenErank && !rivenRrank && !bonusAD){ // for validation to all boxes
console.log('Fill the all boxes');
return false;
}
var rivenHP = 558.48 + (86 * level);
var rivenAD = 56.04 + (3 * level) + bonusAD;
var rivenARM = 24.376 + (3.2 * level);
var rivenMR = 32.1 + (1.25 * level);

var rivenQDMG = 10 + (20 * rivenQrank) + (rivenAD * (.4 + .05 * rivenQrank));
var rivenWDMG = 50 + (30 * rivenWrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
var rivenEDMG = 90 + (30 * rivenErank) + (rivenAD - 56.04);
var rivenRDMG = 100 + (50 * rivenRrank) + (rivenAD - 56.04) * .6;
  console.log(rivenQDMG);
  console.log(rivenWDMG);
  console.log(rivenEDMG);
  console.log(rivenRDMG);
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #a6a6a6;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 align="center"> Riven Damage Calculator </h1>

  <center>
    <p align="center"> Input your level: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_LEVEL"> <br>
    <p align="center"> Input your Q rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_Q"> <br>
    <p align="center"> Input your W rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_W"> <br>
    <p align="center"> Input your E rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_E"> <br>
    <p align="center"> Input your R rank (Rank 1 would be 0): </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_R"> <br>
    <p align="center"> Input your bonus AD: </p> <input type="text" id="RIVEN_AD"> <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="myBoop()"> Calculate </button>
  </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

@StuntHacks is correct about taking the values from an input. Your script is also placed in the wrong order. Your script should go last just before the body because you are a calling `getElementById()` on something that is not referenced yet.

```
<div id="riven"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("riven");
</script>
```